# How to obtain Avenir Black as a font-family in HTML5?

Tags: css, html, fonts

I'm currently writing a web page in HTML5, trying to obtain Avenir Black as a font for a block of text. However, it seems that each time that I define it as the font family, it doesn't work, and displays the default font instead. Now I don't really want to modify the CSS file since it's only for one block of text... What's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    <p style="font-family : Avenir Black ; font-size : 54pt"> SAMPLE </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Displays https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9WMj.jpg.

Comment: "Only for one block of text" is not a valid reason to use inline styling...

Answer (score 5):

Font-family names with spaces need apostrophes as Evan Mosseri has said, so:
`<p style="font-family : 'Avenir Black' ; font-size : 54pt"> SAMPLE </p>`
However, the font must also be installed on the computer running the browser, which doesn't seem likely for browsers in general, even if it is installed on your computer.

You can 1) give up and use something like Arial Black, or 2) use an image, or 3) find and purchase a downloadable Avenir Black font.  For the latter, try a search for "Avenir Black WOFF."  Type as images is a Bad Idea™ and best left alone for a number of reasons, not the least of which is accessibility.

It would not have provided a complete solution this time, but whenever CSS doesn't work, the CSS Validator is your friend:  http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Edited to add: You should always use an alternative list in font-family, ending with one of the generic font names.  So, in your case:
`font-family: 'Avenir Black', 'Arial Black', sans-serif;`
That way, if Avenir Black is installed on the computer running the browser, it will be used. If not, Arial Black will be used.  If neither is available, you will get *some* sans-serif font instead of the default font.

A Google search for "fonts similar to Avenir Black" turns up the Google font Nunito: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Nunito  It's free, or you can get the real Avenir Black for $30.

Comment: Thank you! I was so sure the font was installed because I had found it in Word, but looking in the Font book, it seems not... Thanks for helping a total beginner with his first site!

Comment: Even if it's on your computer, it also has to be on the computers of everyone who views the site.  If not, they'll get the default font, probably Times New Roman.  If you really need this, try a search for "WOFF" and then one for "Avenir Black WOFF."

Comment: *{time passes}* Downloadable web fonts for the Avenir Black face now seem to be pretty available for free.  Do note that doing thin incurs a download penalty in time and bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Try `font-family:"Avenir Black"` but you may need a font face declaration

Comment: Yep, you need quotes for names with spaces in it!